# Rails gsub fails to show symbol for \u20B9 (Rupee Symbol)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails gsub method from NumberHelper shows symbols till unicode '\u20B8' but fails to show any symbol '\u20B9'.

Rails - 3.0.5
Ruby - 1.9.2-p0

In Rails console, execute the following:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > value = "123.45"
 => "123.45" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > unit = "\u20B9"
 => "\u20B9" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > puts unit
₹
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > format = "%u %n"
 => "%u %n" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > format.gsub(/%n/, value).gsub(/%u/, rup)
 => "\u20B9 123.45" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > format.gsub(/%n/, value).gsub(/%u/, "\u20B8")
 => "₸ 123.45" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >
```

Please advice why is this behaviour with gsub?

Comment: By the way, gsub isn't from NumberHelper, its a core method on ruby's String class.

Comment: yep true. that was a typo mistake, i wanted to mention number_from_currency from NumberHelper, then finally drilled down that gsub used in number_from_currency is the one which is not printing the symbol properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the problem is.  It's doing exactly as you expect.  IRB is showing you the `#inspect` output, which produces the string with the quotes and the unicode escape sequence.  Just `puts` it to actually see it rendered:

```
>> unit = "\u20B9"
=> "₹"
>> value = "123.45"
=> "123.45"
>> format = "%u %n"
=> "%u %n"
>> puts format.gsub(/%n/, value).gsub(/%u/, unit)
₹ 123.45
=> nil
```

The above is straight from a pry session.

EDIT | Note also that your use of `#gsub` is odd.  You can use a format string for what you're doing:

```
>> puts "%s %.2f" % [unit, value]
=> ₹ 123.45
```

Comment: Did you `puts` it, or did you just let IRB output it for you?  See my note about `#inspect`.

Comment: Thank you puts does print the symbol.

Comment: That's basically just how IRB works.  For most things, it calls `#inspect` on the value.